# Building libcec for fedora without usb-CEC adapter

Tags: linux, hdmi

I am trying to CEC with libcec-2.1.4 on Fedora without Pulse-Eight USB-CEC adapter. I build the source per README  but the cec-client seems require the USB-CE adapter.

```
root## echo "standby 0" | cec-client -s
WARNING: [               0] libCEC has not been compiled with detection code for the Pulse-Eight  USB-CEC Adapter, so the path to the COM port has to be provided to libCEC if this adapter is being used

root# echo h | cec-client -s d 1
opening a connection to the CEC adapter...
DEBUG:   [               1] unregistering all CEC clients
DEBUG:   [               2] Broadcast (F): osd name set to 'Broadcast'
ERROR:   [            3507] error opening serial port '1': No such file or directory
ERROR:   [            3508] could not open a connection (try 1)
ERROR:   [            6343] error opening serial port '1': No such file or directory
ERROR:   [            6343] could not open a connection (try 2)
ERROR:   [            8233] error opening serial port '1': No such file or directory
ERROR:   [            8233] could not open a connection (try 3)
ERROR:   [            9492] error opening serial port '1': No such file or directory
ERROR:   [            9492] could not open a connection (try 4)
NOTICE:  [           10498] connection opened
ERROR:   [           10498] could not start CEC communications
unable to open the device on port 1
```

I also built already the source on Raspberry Pi and it is successfully working TV on/off/HDMI input change etc even without the CEC adapter. So I believed there would be a way to make it work on Fedora box but not working for now. If you have any guid for configuring the source for build, please let me know. There would be some configure option as build for raspberry. 
Or if you know other open source for HDMI CEC, please let me know.

thanks

Comment: Well, yeah. Without a CEC device (either PulseEight's, or the one built into the RPi), you can't really have a client which connects to your CEC device. What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: the libcec on Raspberry is working even without the the adapter. That is, my rasberry is connected to Samsung TV via HDMI cable. And the cec-client on Pi can control the TV like on/off/change HDMI input from HDMI1 to HDMI2, and go back to HDMI1 . What I am trying to do is same on Fedora.

Comment: The RPi HAS a CEC adapter, built into the Broadcom GPU. Your computer's video card does not.

Comment: Sneftel, Thank you for your reply. I got it thanks to you.